# Asp.net Multi-language web application

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, multilingual

I am building a simple APP in ASP.NET MVC. Can anyone provide me any help how to do it as multilanguage site , storing language in session and working with sessions, link , help or tutorial , to change the language in server side , i post news in that cms , so when i press englisH , it should show me the text in english , spanish and so on..

Comment: use Code Project https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526827/MVC-Basic-Site-Step-Multilingual-Site-Skeleton to have basic understanding of multilingual and after than you can explore advance functionality according to your requirement

Comment: I need to work with sessions and then communicate with controller.

Answer (score 0):

(this is done in vb but if c# is desired, code converters are available and but the principle is the same)
this could be done with a xml file with a structure like this.

```
<globalization>
    <!-- the lang attribute is a made up attribute. it helps with search
         further on-->
    <content lang="fr">
        <title>je suis un titre</title>
        <text>et ceci est un paragraphe</title>
    </content>
    <content lang="en">
        <title>this is a title</title>
        <text>and this is a paragraph</title>
    </content>
</globalization>
```

and all you need is to do is in your back end change your html depending on what language is selected...
example of html:

```
<body>
    <asp:button runat="server" id="btnLangFr" text="Fr"/>
    <asp:button runat="server" id="btnLangEn" text="En"/>
    <asp:label runat="server" id="lblTitle" />
    <asp:label runat="server" id="lblParagraph" />
<body>
```

example of backend:

```
Protected Sub btnLangEn(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) handles btnLangEn.click
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument() //defines xmldoc
    xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("globalization.xml")) //gets .xml file
    Dim root As XmlElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement //defines root
    'next line sets a list of all the <content> tags
    Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = root.GetElementsByTagName("lang")
    'insert code to change the <asp:label> tags to be equal to the text 
    'between the corresponding xml tags
End Sub
```

to get the correct `content` tag you will need to make a loop that looks for the correct `lang` attribute

once found, save the tag in a variable (ex. `Dim ActiveLang as xmlElement = root.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index of loop)`)

then you can get the text of the desired tags like so.. `activeLang.GetElementsByTagName("title")(0).InnerText`
and make lines of code like this:

```
lblTitle.text = activeLang.GetElementsByTagName("title")(0).InnerText
```

Comment: Would you mind to reformat your question, so the horizontal scrollbars will disappear?

Comment: I need to work with sessions and then communicate with controller.

Comment: oh my apologies, I am not all that familiar with mvc if that is what you are talking about